# Java Bytebuffer can only read sequentially?

Tags: java, performance, byte, bytebuffer, memory-mapped-files

I am mapping a file to memory and reading it back with java's ByteBuffer. This proves to be a really fast way of reading large files. However, I can only read the values sequentially. Meaning that once I read them `buffer.getInt()`the buffer pointer moves to the next bytes. So If I want to use a value more than once I have to store it to another variable:

`int a = buffer.getInt()`

I am noticing that this approach of copying a piece of memory to another is taking a long time (especially with a very large file) compared to just reading bytes. Is there a way I can re-read those bytes instead of copying them?

Answer (score 1):

Just use position(int) to seek in ByteBuffer. Then you can read from anywhere.

```
ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
byte[] data=new byte[10];
buffer.position(100);
//read 10 from postion 100
buffer.get(data);
```